# How to remove package from internal git repo

Tags: r, git, rstudio, package-management

We have created an internal git repo in R studio package manager. If at some point I wanted to remove the package and publish it again, how do I remove the package from the repo?

We are able to remove the git-builder from source. Now since this source is being subscribed by package the expectation was the package should also remove from git-repo.

This was the command we used

```
rspm delete repo --name=git-repo
```

and this command helped us to remove the package from source only

```
rspm delete git-builder --name=package name --source=source name
```

Please help us to decode what are we missing.

Comment: Did you try `git rm filename` command in `git` command line? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

Comment: You just want to remove it from your folder or remove it from the entire history?

Comment: I have to remove the entire history from Rstudio package manager